# send mail with progress bar using Perl

Tags: css, perl

I'm having problem with my send mail script. Mostly the problem is all about the progress bar. I want when I click submit that the progress bar starts moving and ends when the sending done.

Well, I have tried to take similar examples [CGI::ProgressBar](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::ProgressBar) but I can't make it work.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser);
use CGI;
use MIME::Lite;
use CGI::ProgressBar qw/:standard/;

$| = 1; # Do not buffer output

my $CGI = CGI->new();

my $from_email = $CGI->param("from_email");
my $from_name = $CGI->param("from_name");
my $subject = $CGI->param("subject");
my $receipts = $CGI->param("receipts");
my $message  = $CGI->param("message");

# Newline format. send message to each email listed
my $output = join "\n", split " ", $receipts;  

if ($from_email, $from_name, $subject, $receipts, $message) {
my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
        # From Name: John Deo And Sent From Email: johndeo@mail.com
        From     => "$from_name <$from_email>",
        To       => $output,
        Subject  => $subject,
        Data     => $message

);
# Support HTML Message
$msg->attr("content-type" => "text/html");  
$msg->send;

if ($msg) {   # if mail starts sending
print progress_bar( -from=>1, -to=>100 );
for (1..100){
        print update_progress_bar;
        # Print ProgressBar
        $progressbar_html = qq{<div class="box">
    <div id="progressbar">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Sending... 1%</div>
</div>
};
        sleep 1;

}
print $response = "Message Sent Successfully";
exit;
}

if(!$msg) {
print $response = "Message Failed To Send";
}
}

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print <<START_HTML;

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Mailer</title>
<style type="text/css">
.box {
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.96);
    text-align: center;
}
#progressbar {
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 2px;
}
#progressbar > div {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 1%;
    height: 18px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.text {
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
<label>From Email
<input type="text" name="from_email" />
<br />
<br />
From Name
<input type="text" name="from_name" />
</label>
<p>
  <label>Subject
  <input type="text" name="subject" />
  </label>
</p>
<p>
  <label>Receipts
  <textarea name="receipts"></textarea>
  </label>
</p>
<p>
  <label>message
  <textarea name="message"></textarea>
  </label>
</p>
<p>
  <label>Send
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </label>
</p>
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

$progressbar_html
<p>$response</p>
</body>
</html>

START_HTML
```

Comment: [MIME::Lite](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite) starts with a big caveat: "MIME::Lite is not recommended by its current maintainer. There are a number of alternatives, like Email::MIME or MIME::Entity and Email::Sender, which you should probably use instead. "

Comment: The first problem would be that `$msg->send` doesn't return until after the message has been sent. You would need to use a mail sender package with asynchronous API. Then you would need to add some Javascript on the client side to request status updates from the server to be able to update the progress bar. Such a thing can't be achieved with CGI.

Comment: [Crossposted from PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1229766).

Comment: so u mean such thing cant be achieved with cgi. so only web framework like mojo, dancer crystal

Comment: *u mean such thing cant be achieved with cgi* - No, I don't believe that anyone has said anything even close to that.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I wouldn't suggest using a module which looks like it was abandoned over eight years ago.

Secondly, I'm really not sure how you think this is going to work. In pseudo-code, your program looks like this:

- Set up CGI object
- Extract mail parameters
- Create mail
- Send mail
- Show a progress bar which updates every second for a hundred seconds

The main problem is the fact that the line that says `$msg->send` is where the mail is sent. Once that line has been executed, the mail has gone. There's no point in creating and updating a progress bar after what you're showing the progress of has completed.

You need to do something more like this:

- Set up CGI object
- Extract mail parameters
- Create mail
- Set up and display progress bar
- Send mail (including regular call-back to update the progress bar)

Of course, it's that last part that is tricky. I haven't looked at MIME::Lite for years (it's mostly deprecated these days) but skimming the documentation, I can't see any way to make asynchronous callbacks from within the mail sending code.

One approach would be to create an email for every person in the recipients list. That way you could send them one at a time and update the progress bar after sending each one. But that's not a particularly efficient way to email multiple people.