# progessbar in cgi using perl

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl

so far everything is working. but the prolem is with the progressar to start wen sending mails.

i have found it hard for me to implement all examples of progressbar in cgi.

the documentations are not so clear to me how progressbar is done in cgi.

maybe someone can help me with my above code. so can practice and get idea how the progrssbar works with cgi. so can implement it on my future projects

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use lib '.';
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use CGI;
use MIME::Lite;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

my $q = new CGI();

my $host =   "localhost";
my $usr =    "root";
my $pwd =    "";
my $dbname = "tbl_users";

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$dbname:$host", $usr, $pwd, {
                                  AutoCommit => 0,
                                  RaiseError => 1, 
                                  }) or die $DBI::errstr;

my $sub = $q->param("sub");
my $msg = $q->param("msg");
my $success;

if ($sub) {
my $getemails = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT EMAIL FROM USERS");
$getemails->execute();
my $dbemails = $getemails->fetchall_arrayref;
my $emails = join ',',map{$_->[0]}@$dbemails;

my $to = '';
my $from = 'noreplay@site.com';
my $subject = $sub;
my $message = "

$msg 

";

my $MSG = MIME::Lite->new(
                 From     => $from,
                 To       => $to,
                 Bcc      => $emails,
                 Subject  => $subject,
                 Data     => $message
                 );

$MSG->send; 
$success = "mail was sent successfully";

}

$dbh->disconnect || die "$DBI::errstr\n";

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print <<START_HTML;

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Mail Send</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: white;
        font-family: Verdana;
        font-size: small;
        color: black
    }
    #trough {
        background-color: silver;
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 24px
    }
    #bar {
        background-color: #669900;
        height: 24px;
        width: 1%
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Mail My DB Customers</h1>

<div id="form" style="display: block; margin: auto; width: 350px">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Send Mail</legend>

        <form name="mail"  method="post" onSubmit="return sendMail(this)">


        Subject: <input type="text" name="sub" size="20"><br>
        Message: <input type="text" name="msg" size="20"><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Send Mail">
        </form>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<div id="progress" style="margin: auto; width: 350px">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Sending...</legend>

        <div id="trough"><div id="bar"></div></div>

        Percent: <span id="percent">0</span>%
    </fieldset>
</div>

<span>$success</span>

<div id="debug"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // When the form is submitted.
    function sendMail(frm) {

        // Show the progress indicator.
        document.getElementById("progress").style.display = "block";

        // Wait a bit and make ajax requests.
        setTimeout("getProgress()", 1000);

        return true;
    }

    // Poll for our progress.
    function getProgress() {
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
                gotProgress(ajax.responseText);
            }
        };

        ajax.open("GET", "upload.pl" + Math.floor(Math.random()*99999), true);
        ajax.send(null);
    }

    // Got an update
    function gotProgress(txt) {


        // Get vars outta it.
        var percent = 0;

        // Was it an error?
        if (stat[0] == "error") {
            document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML += "error: " + stat[1];
            setTimeout("getProgress()", 1000);
            return false;
        }

        // Separate the vars.
        var parts = stat[1].split("&");

        for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            var halves = parts[i].split("=");


            if (halves[0] == "percent") {
                percent = halves[1];
            }

        }

        document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML += "percent:" + percent + "<br>\n";

        // Update the display.
        document.getElementById("bar").style.width = parseInt(percent) + "%";
        document.getElementById("percent").innerHTML = percent;

        // Set another update.
        setTimeout("getProgress()", 1000);
        return true;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>



START_HTML
```

Comment: @Abigail upload.pl is the filename of the script, thats what i tried. so i just need help in both either JavaScript and perl code so wen i click send the progressbar starts and ends when send done

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you misunderstand how Ajax works. It sounds like your Ajax call is re-requesting your main CGI program and that's probably not going to work. The Ajax call should be to a simpler program which returns a (usually) JSON response which contains the data that the main page requires.

But also, the [fundamental problems that I mentioned to you in February](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54734102/7231) still exist. Your email is sent using a single call to `MIME::Lite::send()`, so there is nothing for your progress bar to report on. The progress is 0% before the call is made and 100% once it has returned.

Comment: (so there is nothing for your progress bar to report on. The progress is 0% before the call is made and 100% once it has returned.) . yes but i want the progressbar to function. tho the help i wanted is how i can fix the ajax with the perl code to move progress from 0% to 100% if sent